# Proper way to get slot values in optimizers

Tags: tensorflow

I have an AdamOptimizer. I want to debug my model, so I want to get diagnostics. I am aware of opt.get_slot() method, but unfortunately it always returns None.

I tried the following:

- Getting it after I called opt.minimize(loss)
- Running optimization step several times

In both cases I get None. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's a more generic way not specific to slots, you do `minimize` or `apply_gradients` call inside `capture_vars` decorator and then filter out the variables you want based on their `variable.name`

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture_vars():
  """Decorator to capture global variables created in the block.
  """

  micros = int(time.perf_counter()*10**6)
  scope_name = "capture_vars_"+str(micros)
  op_list = []
  with tf.variable_scope(scope_name):
    yield op_list

  g = tf.get_default_graph()
  for v in tf.global_variables():
    scope = v.name.split('/', 1)[0]
    if scope == scope_name:
      op_list.append(v)

with u.capture_vars() as adam_vars:
  train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grad_new.to_grads_and_vars())
sess.run([v.initializer for v in adam_vars])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself. I should call opt.get_slot(var, slot) where var is a variable, not the loss function. So, I though, that it should return a vector of all moments and rates, but I should specify which variables I want to inspect.